Searching for the right way to use environment variables in a Nx/Angular project
Context
I am trying to take over an Angular/Nx project (the backend is not relevant here) that the initial developer has left to the company without any documentation and almost no knowledge transfer. This project is not based on a stack I already used (I known the languages but not so much the configurations), hence, there are a lot of concepts that I am trying to understand at the same time ...
Environment variables were apparently set following an old pattern using environment.[environement].ts files, which from my current understanding is an Angular implementation that wouldn't work with Nx. Most of that part is commented and the variables must currently be commented/uncommented manually.
My goal
I am trying to re-automate the environment variables again.
The changes
By following this explanation: https://nx.dev/recipes/angular/use-environment-variables-in-angular
from what I understood, I made the following stage
In project.json, I have added the following variables under "targets" > "build" > "options" >
"define": {
  "environment.dev.api": [masked],
  "environment.dev.clientId":  [masked],
  "environment.dev.redirect_uri":  [masked],
  
  "environment.staging.api":  [masked],
  "environment.staging.clientId":  [masked],
  "environment.staging.redirect_uri":  [masked],
  
  "environment.prod.api":  [masked],
  "environment.prod.clientId":  [masked],
  "environment.prod.redirect_uri":  [masked]
}

Under [application]\src\app, I have also add a file named type.d.ts which contains:
declare const environment: {
    dev: {
        api: string;
        clientId: string;
        redirect_uri: string;
    };
    staging: {
        api: string;
        clientId: string;
        redirect_uri: string;
    };
    prod: {
        api: string;
        clientId: string;
        redirect_uri: string;
    };
  };

The issue
When I try to run the application using npx nx run [app]:serve --port 4300, I get error:
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(define).
What am I doing wrong? What is the right way to re-automate the environment variables?
More context details
Angular version
In package.json I have the following:
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "17.3.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "17.3.9",
    "@angular/common": "17.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "17.3.9",
    "@angular/core": "17.3.9",
    "@angular/forms": "17.3.9",
    "@angular/material": "17.3.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "17.3.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "17.3.9",
    "@angular/router": "17.3.9",
    (...)
    "@nx/angular": "19.0.4",
    (...)
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "17.3.7",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "17.3.7",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "17.3.7",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "17.4.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "17.4.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "17.4.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~17.3.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "17.3.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "17.3.9",
    (...)
    "@schematics/angular": "17.3.7",
    (...)
    "jest-preset-angular": "14.0.4",
    (...)
  }

More details after comments
projects.json contains
"build": {
  "executor": "@nx/angular:browser-esbuild",

This line was set by the former developer and I'm not sure of the impacts if I change it.
I am currently reading this: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/22503

Which executor are you using for the build? According to the doc you linked, it needs to be either @nx/angular:application or @angular-devkit/build-angular:application

"executor": "@nx/angular:browser-esbuild" ... This was set by the initial developer and I am currently not aware of the consequences if I change it.

define is only available for the application executor, as stated in the docs you linked. To migrate, you can use the following migration: nx generate convert-to-application-executor. Afterwards you should be able to use the define build option.

Thank you. But should I do it? I have no idea why the former developer used "esbuild" and not "application".

@TTT Esbuild and application are very similar in what they are doing, just the options are a bit different. The application builder is future-proof and the default for fresh Angular projects. If I were you, I would definitely try it.

After this change, when running I get error The "paths[1]" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object / TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "paths[1]" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object in file [app]/node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\tools\webpack\configs\common.js:275:24
Again, not sure if I can change this, I'll investigate a bit.

Derudo - According to https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/28997 , I think I understand that there may currently be an incompatibility between "Application" executor and Webpack's 'common.js' file. Maybe that is the reason why former developer was using "esbuild" instead...

I'm thinking that maybe a solution would be to extend "esbuild" executor schematics...
But so far I'm not sure of the complexity of doing this... and can't find where the "define" build option is defined in "application" executor schematic. This may be a wrong track...
